# Localization Settings DB Error: insufficient permissions

Tags: settings, administer

Civicrm 4.7.24 Drupal 7
EC2 Server
Amazon RDS DB

Hey guys I am trying to set the localization settings in my CIVICRM instance but whenever I go to civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1

I get the following error

`Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: insufficient permissions
Return to home page.`

The user has 
`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, TRIGGER, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON att2.* TO 'att'@'10.0.%.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

here is the backtrace

```
#0 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: insufficient permissions", -26, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain [n...")
#4 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-26, 16, (Array:2), "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain [n...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -26, NULL, NULL, "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain [n...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -26, NULL, NULL, "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain [n...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-26, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1142 ** CREATE VIEW command denied to user 'att'@'10.0.10.196' for t...")
#10 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain")
#12 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain")
#13 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1635): DB_DataObject->_query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain")
#14 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(362): DB_DataObject->query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain")
#15 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1949): CRM_Core_DAO->query("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW civicrm_domain_view AS SELECT * FROM civicrm_domain")
#16 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Localization.php(88): CRM_Core_DAO::checkTriggerViewPermission(TRUE)
#17 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(564): CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization->buildQuickForm()
#18 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#19 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization), "display")
#20 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization), "display")
#21 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#22 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#23 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Localization", "Languages, Currency, Locations", NULL)
#24 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#25 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#26 /var/www/html/att/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#27 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("admin", "setting", "localization")
#28 /var/www/html/att/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#29 /var/www/html/att/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#30 {main}
```

Comment: Figured it out, needed to give the SQL user CREATE VIEW rights

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, needed to give the SQL user CREATE VIEW rights